# 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command: Even when there is nothing about perl?

Tags: perl, mingw

Ok, I just installed MinGW on my PC and to used `g++` command on `cmd` and it says,

```
'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
```

I just checked `PATH` and it is as I should expect, there is `g++` directory and `perl` is not anywhere in the list. Same happens when I use `gcc`. But everything is alright when i use `python`. Now this problem is driving me insane and compels me to think that my PC is a sick Idiot who likes to suffer from strange diseases which have never been documented.

Yes, I can just `cd` into g++ directory and do what I need but thats too much of hard work every time. Any solutions?

Just to mention I used to program in `perl`(don't know what I was thinking) but I my PC has gone several changes, partitioning removal, program uninstallation since.

Comment: So, if you invoke `g++` (no matter how) through the `PATH` environment, you get this error? I'm a bit confused by the wording of your question.

Comment: Yes, in the command prompt, In Notepad++ console, In netbeans compilation they say the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the first "g++" found in your PATH is a script that contains a "perl" command or which starts with a shebang line that specifies "perl" without giving a full and correct path to a perl executable.

Comment: Have you faced that problem before? If not, thats kind of Shelock Holmes reasoning. :)

Comment: "Elementary my dear @Shubham."